# contenteditable iframe editable height limit

Tags: iframe, yui, contenteditable

I'm using the yui editor. I want to know if it possible to limit the editable height area.

ex: height:300px, so over 300px, the carret stop writting.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html:

<textarea id="countMe" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
<div class="theCount">Lines used: <span id="linesUsed">0</span><div>js:
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var lines = 10;
var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');

$('#countMe').keydown(function(e) {

    newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
    linesUsed.text(newLines);

    if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
        linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        linesUsed.css('color', '');
    }
});
```

});

You can do some code on your editor panel when user enter characters & calculate length and return false if limit exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple jQuery that can work on iExplorer, Firefox and Crome:

```
 $('#my_frame').load(function () {  
        $(this).height($(this).contents().find("html").height()+20);
    });
```

I add 20 pixels just to avoid any scroll bar, but you may try a lower bound.

Comment: You dont need to limit the area?

Comment: you are setting the editable area height (iframe). I already can do this: var myConfig = {  height: '200px'}; var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('editor', myConfig); myEditor.render(); I want to limit the text in the editable area to 200px. Over 200px if you press the 'enter' key, it should return false so no other new line is created.

Comment: In other words, if I have an editable area of 200 px (height), I ONLY want this area for editing text. (no scrolling, no new line, no overflow)